How to configure the MatchKind of the Aho-Corasick algorithm in the replace_many function
From polars sources, I found that
fn build_ac(patterns: &StringChunked, ascii_case_insensitive: bool) -> PolarsResult<AhoCorasick> {
    AhoCorasickBuilder::new()
        .ascii_case_insensitive(ascii_case_insensitive)
        .build(patterns.downcast_iter().flatten().flatten())
        .map_err(|e| polars_err!(ComputeError: "could not build aho corasick automaton {}", e))
}

I think they use the default, MatchKind::Standard, and this configuration does not fit my case.
My case
let patterns = &["abcd", "abc", "ab"];
let haystack = "asd abcd asd abc asd";

let ac = AhoCorasick::builder()
    .ascii_case_insensitive(true)
    .match_kind(MatchKind::Standard)
    .build(patterns)
    .unwrap();

let result = ac.replace_all(&haystack, &["1", "2", "3"]);
println!("{}", result)

When I use MatchKind::Standard I get
asd 3cd asd 3c asd

But I want the result to be
asd 1 asd 2 asd

So I need MatchKind::LeftmostFirst or MatchKind::LeftmostLongest for my case.
How can I select the MatchKind in the replace_many function instead of writing another function and using the map function?

I don't understand: are you using Polars, or aho-corasick directly?

I use Polars and used Aho-Corasick for the demo of my case. I want to select the MatchKind type in the replace_many function.

Well, if it's hardcoded, you can't change it other than with patching (and potentially sending a PR/opening an issue in Polars).
